# Override external plugin version in precompiled script plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle build tool. I have a precompiled Gradle script plugin X, lets say this is a convention plugin. In build.gradle of plugin I define dependency on another external plugin Y.

plugin X:build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.rivancic.y:y-gradle-plugin:${versionYPlugin}"
}
```

plugin X:gradle.properties

```
versionYPlugin:1.0.0
```

Then in my main project, I apply precompiled script plugin X and I want to manually set version of external plugin Y. Is that possible? I can't find a way to override the plugin Y version from A.

If I define in project A:gradle.properties the version

```
versionYPlugin=1.1.0
```

it doesn't help, still version 1.0.0 is being resolved.

Is there any other way if I want that external plugin version can be dynamically set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing projects and build time vs. application time.
`X:build.gradle` is the build file of your plugin.
Before build `A` can apply `X`, `X` needs to be built.
The build of `X` is a totally separate build.
A project property you have on project `A` has nothing to do with the build of `X`, so cannot influence the build of `X`, no matter whether this is `buildSrc`, an included build, or a standalone build.

If `X` is `buildSrc` or an included build, you could consider some way to reuse the `gradle.properties` of A during the build time, but as you want to influence from the consumer, I guess it is as standalone build or you could change it in the build of `X` directly.

So as `X` is probably a standalone build, when `A` wants to apply it, it is already built and has a metadata file where the version of `Y` is contained that was defined in `X` when building it.

To use a different version of `Y`, you have to make sure it is in the build script class path of `A`. You could for example do `plugins { id("com.rivancic.y") version "3.1.0" apply false }` so that it is in the build script class path of A and is used instead of the version that `X` depends on.
Or you could define it as `buildSrc` `runtimeOnly` dependency just to put it to the class path of all the build scripts.
...

Comment: Before I just had plain script plugin and I could override external plugins with gradle property as plugins were applied over buildscript block in the script plugin. Now I managed to overwrite the external plugin version with plugins{} apply false and buildscript classpath dependencies specification, while I still have issues trying out the solution with the buildSrc implementation approach. Will create test project with bootstrap plugin to try and isolate the issue. Many thanks for an insightful answer!